# Spring boot - jsr352 batch implementation - Beans not getting reference in jobxml

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing, jsr352

I am implementing a batch application using springboot 2.4.3 + jsr352. There is a simple batchlet class(sleepybatchlet) defined. I am trying to reference it in the JSL. but It fails saying classnotfound exception when the job is started using joboperator.

sleepy-batchlet.xml:

```
<job xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/jobXML_1_0.xsd" restartable="true" version="1.0" id="sleepy-batchlet">
    <step id="step1">
        <batchlet ref="sleepyBatchlet">
            <properties>
                <property name="sleep.time.seconds" value="#{jobParameters['sleep.time.seconds']}" />
            </properties>
        </batchlet>
    </step>
</job>
```

Below is my batchlet class which is annotated with @Named

@Named
public class SleepyBatchlet extends AbstractBatchlet{

```
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SleepyBatchlet.class.getName());
private Map<ReportMetaData,byte[]> pdfMetadataMap;

/**
 * Logging helper.
 */
protected static void log(String method, Object msg) {
    System.out.println("SleepyBatchlet: " + method + ": " + msg);
    // logger.info("SleepyBatchlet: " + method + ": " + String.valueOf(msg));
}

/**
 * This flag gets set if the batchlet is stopped.  This will break the batchlet
 * out of its sleepy loop.
 */
private volatile boolean stopRequested = false;

/**
 * The total sleep time, in seconds.
 */
@Inject
@BatchProperty(name = "sleep.time.seconds")
String sleepTimeSecondsProperty;
private int sleepTime_s = 3;

@Inject
private JschFileUtil jschFileUtil;

@Override
public String process() throws Exception {

    log("process", "entry");
    System.out.println("Test");
    return "exitStatus";
}

/**
 * Called if the batchlet is stopped by the container.
 */
@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    log("stop:", "");
    stopRequested = true;
}
```

}

Defined the bean in java configuration class as well.

```
@Autowired
private SleepyBatchlet sleepyBatchlet;
@Bean
public Batchlet fooBatchlet() {
    return sleepyBatchlet;
}
```

But for some reason, Its not getting referenced in the JSL.  Can someone please suggest what needs to be done to use the bean created already ?

Comment: You seem to be hitting this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1175. If you provide a minimal project that reproduces the problem, I can try to see if the is a workaround until the issue is fixed.

Comment: sure, let me work on sharing the minimal project

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I added sample springboot+jsr352 application here . https://github.com/MekalaJ/demo

Comment: curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/job' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw 'sleepy-batchlet'

Comment: When we run the job by hitting the rest endpoint, It fails with classnotfound exception

Comment: ok thanks. I will take a look.

Comment: I just tried your example and added an answer. With this change, your example works without the `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine do you have any input on it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202085/springbatch-how-to-process-files-itself-as-a-item. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to reference it in the JSL. but It fails saying classnotfound exception when the job is started using joboperator.

This is because you are referring to the class by its name and not its fully qualified name.

> I added sample springboot+jsr352 application here . github.com/MekalaJ/demo

In your example, you need to update your step definition as follows:

```
        <batchlet ref="com.example.demo.batch.SleepyBatchlet">
            <properties>
                <property name="sleep.time.seconds" value="#{jobParameters['sleep.time.seconds']}" />
            </properties>
        </batchlet>
```

Comment: yeah, this would work but it will try to create a new bean of type sleepybatchlet. not refer the one thats created by @inject/@component.

Comment: do you have any suggestion on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202085/springbatch-how-to-process-files-itself-as-a-item

Comment: I accpted the answer already. Its showing as accpted answer for me.

Comment: I don't see it as accepted, but no worries, the most important thing is that you solved your issue :-) Glad to be of help.